# 10.6.4 Apple Wiki: New just created users can do nothing?

Tags: mac, mac-osx-server, wiki, apple

After update to 10.6.4 there's an issue: any new users that I create in Server Prefs/WGM can't post to their blogs, comment, create wiki pages... They can't do anything!
There's log from Wiki errors (when user DURAK tries to create new blog entry):

```
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/share/caldavd/lib/python/twisted/web/server.py", line 126, in process
self.render(resrc)
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/share/caldavd/lib/python/twisted/web/server.py", line 133, in render
body = resrc.render(self)
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/share/wikid/lib/python/apple_xmlrpc_server/WebAppServer.py", line 90, in render
d = defer.maybeDeferred(function, *args)
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/share/caldavd/lib/python/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 104, in maybeDeferred
result = f(*args, **kw)
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1] --- <exception caught here> ---
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/share/wikid/lib/python/apple_xmlrpc_server/ContentServiceBase.py", line 121, in xmlrpc_addEntry
aPage = ContentEntry.newBundleBasedContentEntry
(path = path, content = content, author = author, title = title, uid = uid, type = kind, versioned = self.versioned, templateName = template)
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/share/wikid/lib/python/apple_wlt/ContentEntry.py", line 794, in newBundleBasedContentEntry
aPage.save('First created', 'created')
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/share/wikid/lib/python/apple_wlt/ContentEntry.py", line 445, in save
revisions.addRevision(self.serializeEntry(revisionAttributes), inComment = comment, inAuthor = updateAuthor, inChangeType = editType)
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/share/wikid/lib/python/apple_utilities/sqlitersion.py", line 36, in _func
result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/share/wikid/lib/python/apple_utilities/sqlitersion.py", line 49, in addRevision
contentPlistStr = plistlib.writePlistToString(inContentDict).decode("utf-8")
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/S-m/Lib-ry/Fr-ks/Python.fr-k/Ver-s/2.6/lib/pyth-2.6/plistlib.py", line 110, in writePlistToString
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/S-m/Lib-ry/Fr-ks/Python.fr-k/Ver-s/2.6/lib/pyth-2.6/plistlib.py", line 94, in writePlist
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/S-m/Lib-ry/Fr-ks/Python.fr-k/Ver-s/2.6/lib/pyth-2.6/plistlib.py", line 251, in writeValue
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/S-m/Lib-ry/Fr-ks/Python.fr-k/Ver-s/2.6/lib/pyth-2.6/plistlib.py", line 280, in writeDict
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/S-m/Lib-ry/Fr-ks/Python.fr-k/Ver-s/2.6/lib/pyth-2.6/plistlib.py", line 238, in writeValue
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/S-m/Lib-ry/Fr-ks/Python.fr-k/Ver-s/2.6/lib/pyth-2.6/plistlib.py", line 171, in simpleElement
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1]   File "/S-m/Lib-ry/Fr-ks/Python.fr-k/Ver-s/2.6/lib/pyth-2.6/plistlib.py", line 221, in _escapeAndEncode
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1] exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1] 'Unparseable html in page, removing whatever was already written.'
[HTTPChannel,5,127.0.0.1] Removing /Library/Collaboration/Users/durak/weblog/27133.page
```

Any "old" user CAN create, modify, comment, etc. 
What can you recommend to fix this issue?

Hope for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update of Wiki server removed this issue.